# Not able to create a node with special characters "-" in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a node in neo4j(version 3.2.3). Below is the cypher query,

```
MERGE (`source-real-address`:SOURCE {Source:{`source-real-address`}})
```

I found in forums to create a node with special characters we should use

> backticks `

in the query. But I couldn't able to create a node with backticks. No error were thrown in the logs.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong in the cypher query. I am started 
to understand neo4j cypher query language.

Note:- I am sending data to neo4j from graylog with the help of neo4j output plugin. I could able to create node without special character fields.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `` {Source:{`source-real-address`}}) `` means that you are trying to use a param named `source-real-address` as the value of the property `Source`. If this is your goal, you can set a param in the Neo4j Browser for test purposes with `:params {"source-real-address":"Some value"}`. If not, you can remove the extra `{` and `}` in the value and use `""` instead of backticks, like this:

```
MERGE (source-real-address:SOURCE {Source:"source-real-address"})
```

Remeber that the value of a property should be `Boolean`, `Integer`, `Float` or `String`.

In Cypher backticks are used to create relationships, labels and variable names with special chars (not for property values).

Comment: Yes I am trying to send the data from the graylog to neo4j by using neo4j output plugin.
I can able to set param in Neo4j Browser and get the value from the param for the property source. But the same thing I couldn't able to do it from the neo4j output plugin.

Below is the sample query i tried and its working fine in Neo4j browser,
*`:params {"dest-mapp-address":"172.29.2.12"}`*

**MERGE ('dest-mapp-address':DESTMAP {destmap:{'dest-mapp-address'}})**

Let me know any thoughts on this..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CREATE` command to create Node with special characters

see this also: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/